# Parsing Table with Cheerio

Tags: jquery, cheerio

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <!-- More things here -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table></table>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>I want this</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <!-- More things here -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

So this is the weird looking HTMl structure. The element I want is the '' element which I have marked in the HTML.

This is the Node Js code I am using to parse the HTML. I am not very familiar with jQuery.

```
const $ = cheerio.load(body);
   $('table').find('tbody tr:nth-child(1)').each(()=> {
       $('td').find('table').each(() => {
            console.log($(this).text())
        })
   })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the structure you show is fixed (number of rows, etc.)...

```
$('table tr:nth-child(2) table:nth-child(2) tr td:nth-child(2)').text()
```

I hope it helps

Comment: i use the same code , but on some part of my code , its not working ,and i dont know why